# Images wont load on mern stack app hosted on hostinger vps

Tags: reactjs, nginx, mern, vps, pm2

I have a mern stack app hosted on a hostinger vps. I am using pm2, express and nginx to serve the files. The app works fine except for the fact that i can not access files and images on my backend, that are located on subfolders of "uploads" folder. Whenever i try to access them, I get "500 (Internal Server Error)"

Here is my backend app.mjs with the exception of the routes.

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/uploads/images", express.static(path.join("uploads", "images")));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    //I Have this like this for testing purposes
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE");

  next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new HttpError("Could not find the route.", 404);
  throw error;
});

const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000, // 60 second timeout
  useFindAndModify: false, //Adicionado por findone and update depcrecated.
};

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, options)
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(5000, "0.0.0.0", () => {
      console.log("Estamos conectados!");
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB disconnected");
  mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, options)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Estamos conectados!");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Here is my part of my nginx conf file without certbot and websocket

```
root /sites/dental/frontend/build;
    index index.html;
    server_name healthtechcv.com www.healthtechcv.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;  # or which other port your app runs on
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /api{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }


    location /uploads{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
.....
```

I have tried granting full permission to the uploads file and it does not work.
Sometimes I get an error saying "Could not find the route."
Everything works fine locally.